# Cloudflare Pages uses different sphinx version depending on commits and one is failing

Tags: python-3.x, python-sphinx, cloudflare, cloudflare-pages

I have a Cloudflare page that uses `python-sphinx`to build docs. For some of my commits, it downloads a different version of sphinx than others and fails to build docs correctly.

What I tried:

- Adding a dummy commit on top of a failing build **seems to fix an issue** and force Cloudflare builder to download the correct sphinx version
- re-running deployments **doesn't** fix the issue
- creating a new branch with the same head(failing commit) and running another deployment **doesn't** fix the issue
- changing between preview/production deployments **has no impact on this issue**

Here is a dummy commit I added to make the docs build correctly

[image]

Commit one result vs. Commit two result

[image: Commit 1 result]
[image: Commit 2 result]

The diff in deployment logs old commits, the left is Commit 1(not working), and the right, Commit two, correctly builds all three tasks and the releases.

https://www.diffchecker.com/ZpV8vE9D

I have tried making different branches and re-run deployments to check whether the sphinx version will change, but it seems like it's bounded the the "old commit". This is also an issue for other Cloudflare Pages, and using preview/production deployments has no impact on this problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue in this case was actually not with sphinx version but with the fact that I was using:

```
git fetch --all
```

Which does not guarantee pulling the tags with it.
The `--all` pull from all remotes instead of "everything" as I thought.

Using `git fetch --tags` instead fixed the issue

Answer (score 1):

Indeed it seems to be a bug, in this case I recommend you to consult directly with CloudFlare support, sometimes they are errors that remain internally in your account and you unbug it, CloudFlare Pages for the moment continues to improve its system, there are details to be corrected.

Comment: Thanks, sometimes deleting the page and creating it fixes the problem. I will contact them next time. Actually this time it was something else so I am closing question